# ReadToEnd missing character c#

Tags: c#, xml, encryption, cryptostream

I have an XML file with information about my `stringConnection` parameters which decrypted with this method:

```
public void DecryptFile(string sInputFileName, string sOutputFileName, string sKey)
{
    DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
    DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
    FileStream fsread = new FileStream(sInputFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    ICryptoTransform desdecrypt = DES.CreateDecryptor();
    CryptoStream cryptostreamDecr = new CryptoStream(fsread, desdecrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

    //Print result
    StreamWriter fsDecrypted = new StreamWriter(sOutputFileName);
    //In this point ReadToEnd return the final xml result decrypted
    fsDecrypted.Write(new StreamReader(cryptostreamDecr).ReadToEnd());
    fsDecrypted.Flush();
    fsDecrypted.Close();
    fsread.Close();
    fsread.Dispose();
}
```

The result would be this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <TU>
    <BD>DataBaseName</BD>
    <SR>ServerName</SR>
    <USR>UserDB</USR>
    <CONT>Pass</CONT>
    <EMP>codCompany</EMP>
    <EMPDES>companyName</EMPDES>
    <SUC>codLocal</SUC>
  </TU>
</NewDataSet>
```

But `ReadToEnd` doesn't return the last label of my XML file, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <TU>
    <BD>DataBaseName</BD>
    <SR>ServerName</SR>
    <USR>UserDB</USR>
    <CONT>Pass</CONT>
    <EMP>codCompany</EMP>
    <EMPDES>companyName</EMPDES>
    <SUC>codLocal</SUC>
  </TU>
</NewDataSet
```

What's wrong with my method?

Comment: You may want to provide the `EncryptFile` method as well. I would also make sure you start adding `using` statements to your code to guarantee proper cleanup of `IDisposable` types.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you are not really reading the `CryptoStream` to the end, because of the way it blocks data (as pointed out [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17377377/181087)). Here is an approach adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9725120) which uses a buffer to read 1024 bytes at a time.

```
public void DecryptFile(string sInputFileName, string sOutputFileName, string sKey)
{
    DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
    DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);

    ICryptoTransform desdecrypt = DES.CreateDecryptor();
    using (FileStream fsread = new FileStream(sInputFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (StreamWriter fsDecrypted = new StreamWriter(sOutputFileName))
    using (CryptoStream cryptostreamDecr = new CryptoStream(fsread, desdecrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    {
        //Print result
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        var read = cryptostreamDecr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        while (read > 0)
        {
            fsDecrypted.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            read = cryptostreamDecr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

You are also missing [`using` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement), which ensure your streams are disposed correctly whether or not your program has an exception.

Comment: `cryptostreamDecr.CopyTo(fsDecrypted)` should work just as well, and be a bit cleaner from a code review perspective.