# NetworkStream can read data only after the sending NetworkStream is closed or disposed

Tags: c#, stream, cryptography, aes, networkstream

I'm writing an app for sending and receiving AES encrypted files. I have two functions, one for sending:

```
public async Task SendFileAsync()
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024];

    using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        // tcpHandler.stream is a NetworkStream
        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV))
        {
            using (Stream fileStream = await selectedFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(tcpHandler.stream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write, true))
                {
                    while (stream.Position < selectedFileSize)
                    {
                        int nowRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); // read bytes from file
                        csEncrypt.Write(buffer, 0, nowRead); // write bytes to CryptoStream (which writes to NetworkStream)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    await tcpHandler.stream.FlushAsync()
}
```

And one for receiving:

```
public async Task ReceiveFileAsync()
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024];
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    int messageLength = tcpHandler.ReadMessageLength();
    int totalBytesRead = 0;

    using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        // tcpHandler.stream is a NetworkStream
        using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV))
        {
            using (var fileStream = await newFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(tcpHandler.stream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read, true)) 
                {
                    while (totalBytesRead < messageLength)
                    {
                        // calculate how many bytes have to be read in this iteration
                        var toRead = Math.Min(buffer.Length, messageLength - totalBytesRead);
                        var nowRead = csDecrypt.Read(buffer, 0, toRead); // read bytes from CryptoStream
                        totalBytesRead += nowRead; // sum read bytes
                        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, nowRead); // write decrypted bytes to file
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that `ReceiveFileAsync()` blocks itself on the last `csDecrypt.Read(buffer, 0, toRead)` as if there wasn't enough data in `csDecrypt` stream. However, when I close (kill the process) the sending application, the receiving application correctly receives the last buffer.

The same thing happens when I change the last parameter of `using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(tcpHandler.stream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write, true))` to `false` - it makes the CryptoStream close the base stream (`tcpHandler.stream`) when it gets disposed.

If I do `tcpHandler.stream.Close()` at the end of `SendFileAsync()` it also helps.

In short, the last buffer I send doesn't get received until I close the sending NetworkStream (`tcpHandler.stream`), either by closing/disposing it or closing the application.

I tried adding `await tcpHandler.stream.FlushAsync()` as a last line of `SendFileAsync()`, but it didn't help. Any ideas what should I do to fix this?

EDIT: Updated code with nested `using` statements.

Comment: Your using blocks are wrong.  They need to be nested (not serial).  the object in the using block are disposed outside the block.  to the object filestream is disposed after the stream is written.

Comment: @jdweng I nested the `using` blocks, but the same thing happens.

Comment: Post updated code.

Comment: @jdweng Posted the code

Comment: You cannot decrypt file until all the data is received.  The encrypted data is in blocks and you can't decrypt a partial block.  The while loop has to read the entire message before trying to decrypt.

Comment: @jdweng But why does it work when I close the network stream?

Comment: The issue may be on send side not flushing the stream when done.  Closing will flush the stream forcing the last bytes to get transmitted.

Comment: @jdweng But I'm flushing the stream in the updated code.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you are using completely different `Key` and `IV` in the both code snippets? You're using the randomly generated `Key` & `IV`. So, how do you think this will work? Just in case, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67563399/14171304).

Comment: @dr.null Yes I'm aware. I removed the part where I'm setting these values because it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: The TCP connection is probably already closed when you dispose the underlying stream.

Comment: @jdweng Currently I'm not disposing the underlying stream.

Comment: Based on your description [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266902/cryptostream-does-not-flush-like-expected/39556645) may be very close to your problem.

Comment: I did an interesting research (will post later here) and I think you already found the answer -> the network stream has to be closed in order for the receiver to be able to read it (at least for the case with `CryptoStream` ).

Answer (score 0):

My testing .NET 5.0 async console apps with a 5 bytes text file with some sleeping to keep the process alive.

Sender app key points:

1. `NetworkStream.FlushAsync` or (`NetworkStream.Flush`)
2. `CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock`
3. `NetworkStream.Close`
4. `TcpClient.Close` (Also closes the NetworkStream)
5. `leaveOpen` parameter on the `CryptoStream` constructor (true -> it leaves the NetworkStream opened, false -> it calls Close on the NetworkStream)

Receiver app key points:

1. `leaveOpen` parameter on the `CryptoStream` constructor (nothing interesting here),

SideNotes:

- Flush causes the all data form the buffer to be written to the underlying stream. It does not close the Stream.
- Close obviously closes the stream
- CryptoStream is auto managing the final cipher block itself on stream close so need to do it expectedly with Flushing.

Pretty much you already had the answer for yourself:

**You have to close the NetworkStream In order for the receiver to be able to receive it.** There are multiple to ways to do it as described.

**Flushing does not close the stream, hence it will not work.**

This behaviour does not depend on the `CryptoStream`. I also tried this with a writing directly to the `NetworkStream` without using encryption -> same results.
**However you can leave the tcp client open, which means you still will have active connection.**
So like you discovered and I tested:

- 1), 2) and 5)true will not work (Network stream will be closed)
- 3), 4) and 5)false will work (Network stream will remain opened)

Here is my testing code (almost the same but still decided to post it):

1. The client:

   ```
    class Program
    {
        static byte[] key = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16 };
        static byte[] iv = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16 };

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
                tcpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8001);
                Stream stream = tcpClient.GetStream(); // NetworkStream

                await SendFileAsync(stream, "test.txt");

                //await stream.FlushAsync();

                //stream.Close();

                //tcpClient.Close();
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        public static async Task SendFileAsync(Stream stream, string filePath)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[1024];

            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(key, iv))//aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(stream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write, false))
                    {
                        int bytesRead;
                        while ((bytesRead = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            csEncrypt.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            //csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```
2. The server:

   ```
    class Program
    {
        static byte[] key = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16 };
        static byte[] iv = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16 };

        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                TcpListener tcpServer = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8001);
                tcpServer.Start();
                var tcpClient = await tcpServer.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

                await ReceiveFileAsync(tcpClient, "text.txt");

                tcpServer.Stop();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        public static async Task ReceiveFileAsync(TcpClient tcpClient, string filePath)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(key, iv))
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                using (BinaryWriter br = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(stream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read, true))
                    {
                        int bytesRead;
                        while ((bytesRead = csDecrypt.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            br.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```